# Need help remembering sci-fi movie from the 90s maybe where someone is sabotaging the crew

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

I saw this movie years ago and can't quite remember it. All I remember is there was a crew trapped in space and they're trying to survive but someone on the crew is sabotaging them. The drinking water gets poisoned so they have to drink their own urine. There's a man with a leg injury that he can't tell is getting really infected and bad because the saboteur gave him these injections that numb his leg.

That's pretty much all I can remember, so if anyone can help me with the title somehow, that would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is **"[Lifepod](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107415/)"**, a 1993 made-for-TV remake of the classic Hitchcock thriller "*[Lifeboat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037017/)*".

> The premise is that there is limited supplies of air, food and water
> on the life pod. The survivors Begin to argue over whether they should
> end the life of one of the survivors (Portrayed by Stan Shaw) in the
> pod that is critically injured. They reason that it would help
> conserve their supplies. Before they can decide on the Issue of
> killing the man he is found dead the next day after they wake up. They
> realize there is a killer with them in the lifepod. Eventually the
> survivors realize that its possible that one of the people in the
> Lifepod could have sabotaged the spacecraft.